# Why can't I successfully call the .put method here?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, json-simple

I made a `JSONArray` object but can't seem to call the .put method on it. Does anyone know why?

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: try removing the simple from the imports, its not the class that  you want

Comment: `org.json.simple.JSONArray` has add method whereas `org.json.JSONArray` has put method that's why `put` is not resolved

Comment: What you won't to .put (key , value)
an array is using .add

Answer (score 2):

It should be **`prevjobs.add("name");`** since [`JSONArray` extends `ArrayList`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java#L19), and that's how items are added to an `ArrayList`.

Also, check the [unofficial javadocs](https://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/index.html), section *Methods inherited from class java.util.ArrayList*.

Finally, if you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> after `prevjobs.` you can see the available methods from the `JSONArray` API.